# How to compare try_convert with filed nullable in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an escape in which I try to pull out a certain population under any conditions.
In one of the conditions I use SQL Server's Try_convert, which can actually return NULL to me.
What happens is this: if it returns me NULL and will actually have a NULL value field it will not give me the answer that I did not ask is null.
Does it have a short and effective solution ??

My code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMortgageDetailsId] 
(@GetFiled nvarchar(8)='00000000')
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

   declare @MortgageDetailsId int = null

   set @MortgageDetailsId= (select top 1 t.id from Table_1 t
       WHERE t.filed1 = TRY_CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING(@GetFiled, 5, 4) + SUBSTRING(@GetFiled, 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(@GetFiled, 1, 2)))

   RETURN @MortgageDetailsId

END
```

The definition of the filed `filed1` is:

```
[filed1] [date] NULL,
```

Comment: So, if i'm understanding correctly, you want rows where the `TRY_CONVERT` returns `NULL`, **AND** where the value of the column isn't `NULL`? If so, this comment is a big hint.

Comment: Yes, I'm need all the rows that this column has `null` and also the `try_convert` returnd `null`

Comment: You can use "filed1 IS NULL"

Comment: but `TRY_CONVERT(date, NULL)` = `NULL`? So just checking for `NULL` on the `TRY_CONVERT` meets both requirements. Think we're missing something here.

Comment: @CetinBasoz - I can't ask it. becouse some of the rows has null and some not

Comment: I need all the rows that compare, This is a function. so it's working but not if it's null. becouse the question is `filed1=null` and not `filed1 is null`

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't ask it"? IS NULL and IS NOT NULL are different things.

Answer (score 0):

Need to ask:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetMortgageDetailsId] 
(@GetFiled nvarchar(8)='00000000')
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

   declare @MortgageDetailsId int = null

   set @MortgageDetailsId= (select top 1 t.id from Table_1 t
       WHERE t.filed1 = (TRY_CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING(@GetFiled, 5, 4) + SUBSTRING(@GetFiled, 3, 2) + SUBSTRING(@GetFiled, 1, 2))))
                      or (@GetFiled='00000000' and t.filed1 is null))

   RETURN @MortgageDetailsId

END
```